# Magento 2 Elastic Search enable but not showing search results

Tags: magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, index

Magento 2 enable elastic and the connection is successful

[image]

but when search from the frontend it is not showing results

Even our elastic search status is **green** and the index key is also generating

Can anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I had the same issue and this resolved it for me:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322623/80697

Comment: @alanjson ok i am checking

Comment: @alanjson i am not getting any error in exception.log