# Null condition present on Category Products Collection Query

Tags: category-products, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.2

Currently I am on Magento 2.4.2 which was upgraded from 2.3.0. The issue which I am facing right now is that I am  not able to see any products displayed on category page.

After debugging the below file:

```
Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider
```

and below function in the above path:

```
public function getCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)
```

I found the collection query which is as below:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (NULL)
```

I guess **WHERE(NULL)** condition might be the culprit here.

Any idea why am I getting this WHERE(NULL) condition and any suggestions to resolve this

Comment: there could be several reasons for product not getting displayed 1st one and most common is reindexing also make sure that your elasticsearch configuration are coorect and working? please confirm

Comment: Yes have indexed too and elastic search configuration are correct as well.. but cant get rid of products not displaying

Comment: @Nisith check is there any third party extension which may affect the sql query. Try disabling third party extensions.

Comment: facing the same issue, I've disabled all the modules but it doesn't work.

Comment: @VirangJethva HAve you found any solution

Comment: yes @Pawankumar disable the third party modules first, in my case Amasty_ShopBy was causing and also there were some issues with attribute backend_type. Here is the link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322516/magento-2-x-elasticsearch-category-products-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

- Disable the third-party modules.
- Make sure elasticsearch is up and running
- Run the below query to see if is there any issue with backend_type in attributes

Show misconfigured attributes:

```
SELECT *
FROM catalog_eav_attribute cea 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
AND backend_type IN ('text')
WHERE 
cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1
```

Set `is_filterable` to `0` to allow category pages to load.

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute cea 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
AND backend_type in ('text')
SET 
cea.is_filterable = 0, cea.is_filterable_in_search = 0
WHERE 
cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1
```

Reindex/Refresh Cache

```
magento indexer:reindex
magento cache:clean
magento cache:flush
```

Original Answer Credit Source : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322623/27583