# After upgrading to magento 2.4.3-p1 catalog search not working

Tags: catalogsearch, reindex, indexing

Elasticsearch 7 is used and all the configuration setting are as same
as given on devdoc.

Elasticsearch connection is also returning Succesfull

When searching any of the product it does not display any product.

As product is available on website and name attribute of product is also set to searchable(Advance search is also enabled).

Search result display as below

[image]

If anyone found the same issue then answer below

TIA

Comment: please run indexing command.

Comment: Done with that reindex is in ready state

Comment: now it's working ?

Comment: No product display on search

Comment: please try this link and update me https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322623/82670

Comment: Its returning like this https://awesomescreenshot.s3.amazonaws.com/image/1843250/21742303-84df17c83385b09ebe407f318201737c.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJSCJQ2NM3XLFPVKA%2F20220208%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220208T053345Z&X-Amz-Expires=28800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=82c517bc058fbebdaebfdaff0ad2d03d55c6d53081d44ef317949dca810cfa69 no product display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133953/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-msquare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to some config problems of **Elasticsearch**.

And `search_request.xml` was also overrided in our custom module.

So If you are upgrading magento website to 2.4.0 or above versions, make sure about your Elasticsearch configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your catalog search engine and change it to Elasticsearch7.

To change search engine value go to Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search and change value as showing in below image.

[image]

After changing the configuration value please run php bin/magento indexer:reindex command and check your search page.

I hope it will help you.